# Debugging ng-click not firing with ui-view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-ng-click

I have an Angular app which uses `'ngCookies'`, `'oc.lazyLoad'`, `'ui.router'`, `'ui.bootstrap'` and `'angular-loading-bar'`. Its config works with `$stateProvider` where all the views and nested views are defined.

The problem that I have is that when I try to use `ng-click` directive inside any nested view, it doesn't work. It works if I put it in the template of a top-most view, like a login screen for example. `ng-repeat` or some custom directives and services work fine.

I've searched through some questions that were already asked, but usually the solutions were trivial (like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29052817/ng-click-not-firing-deep-inside-ui-views) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33238472/ng-click-not-firing)) and they don't apply to my case. In my case `ng-click` won't work even in the simplest example like this one (the initial value of `count` is presented correctly):

```
<button ng-click="count = count + 1" ng-init="count=0" class="btn btn-primary">Correct</button>
{{count}}
```

I understand that template needs to be compiled for the Angular to see that there is an `ng-click` directive inside. But seeing other questions I assume that if `ui-view` loads the template and `ng-click` is directly inside this template, it should work correctly. Can you point me towards a solution that will help me to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: You either have console errors or your template is not compiled. This is quite obvious. Add actual code how you load templates.

Comment: I use customized [SB Admin theme](http://startangular.com/product/sb-admin-angular-theme/). There is no console errors, nothing. It's like I'm pressing the button and it's void. I was hoping there is some obvious thing to check before rolling back each modification I did and to check which one causes problems...

Comment: OK. One day lost. There is nothing like a good rollback session. Anyway I've fixed the problem even though I'm not sure where it was. Is it possible that the problem was caused by creating app with a `angular.module(...).config(cfg).run(run)` and then `cfg.$inject()` and `function cfg(...)` and the same for `run` instead of `angular.module(...).config(...).run(...)`?